# Set Variables in For, in Batch Files

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, set

I'm trying to write a batch file that will take the abbreviation for a month, that's listed in a text file (dates.txt) and then assign the variable `month` with the corresponding numerical value of that month. However, the variable isn't setting, and I'm not sure why. I've read some stuff about loops being the culprit sometimes. I'm not sure if that's a factor here.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%b in (dates.txt) do (
   echo %%b 
   echo %%c
   echo %%d

   if %%c==Jan set month=01
   if %%c==Feb set month=02
   if %%c==Mar set month=03
   if %%c==Apr set month=04
   if %%c==May set month=05
   if %%c==Jun set month=06
   if %%c==Jul set month=07
   if %%c==Aug set month=08
   if %%c==Sep set month=09
   if %%c==Oct set month=10
   if %%c==Nov set month=11
   if %%c==Dec set month=12

   echo %%c
   echo %month% - month
)
```

I've got the initial three `echo` statements to make sure I'm reading the correct data, which I am. I've got the last `echo %month% - month` statement to make sure my variable is setting, and it isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also use an *array* to solve this problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create the array of numbers based on 3-letter month names
set number=100
for %%a in (Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec) do (
   set /A number+=1
   set monthNumber[%%a]=!number:~1!
)

for /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%b in (dates.txt) do (
   echo %%b
   echo %%c
   echo %%d
   set month=!monthNumber[%%c]!
)

echo %month% - month
```

Answer (score 3):

You need `delayed expansion` and `!variables!`:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2,3" %%b in (dates.txt) do (
   echo %%b 
   echo %%c
   echo %%d

   if %%c==Jan set month=01
   if %%c==Feb set month=02
   if %%c==Mar set month=03
   if %%c==Apr set month=04
   if %%c==May set month=05
   if %%c==Jun set month=06
   if %%c==Jul set month=07
   if %%c==Aug set month=08
   if %%c==Sep set month=09
   if %%c==Oct set month=10
   if %%c==Nov set month=11
   if %%c==Dec set month=12

   echo %%c
   echo !month! - month
)
```

Comment: I'll confirm Endoro's claim. Works perfectly for me! Perhaps you've omitted the `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`(which I prefer to put on a separate line...that way, commenting-out the `@ECHO` to enable tracing doesn't disable the `SETLOCAL`) Should also work in its original form if you move the lonely close-parenthesis to the line before the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "month=Jan01Feb02Mar03Apr04May05Jun06Jul07Aug08Sep09Oct10Nov11Dec12"
FOR /f "tokens=1-3" %%b IN (dates.txt) DO (
 ECHO %%c
 CALL SET month=%%month:*%%c=%%
)
SET month=%month:~0,2%
ECHO %month%
ENDLOCAL
```

Here's another way - for interest's sake only as Endoro has the problem solved.